# Button to generate random selection from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time using Firebase, and I was wondering if someone could help me with my iOS app. I want to randomly select a location from my Firebase database upon the user pressing a button. The app will then segue to a tab bar controller where information on the randomly selected location will be. I just need to be pointed in the right direction as querying the database is confusing me. This is a just a part of the database below, as I have other states in it:

```
{
    "locations": {
        "Maryland": {
            "city": "Baltimore",
            "latitude": "39.299236",
            "longitude": "-76.609383"
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Firebase structure as text, no images or links as links change and that breaks the question. Firebase does not have a random function so selecting a node would need to be done within code and there are a vast number of solutions for making a random selection. You may want to consider indexing your nodes with 1 to 100 and then random number generator in code to select one of those, then read that node from Firebase. That may/may not work depending on your use case. Please review [Asking a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Random state? Random City? Random long/lat? Some other random thing? You should update your question with more info and what code you have tried so far.